# FancyBox - Swap out image on click

Tags: jquery, fancybox

When clicking on a thumbnail, FancyBox enlarges that image but what I'd like to do is replace the image being enlarged to another image.

```
<map>
  <area shape="poly" coords="453,862,477,862,478,899,453,900" href="/Images/main.jpg" alt="333" />
</map

$('area').fancybox({
  beforeLoad: function(instance){
   //change href to something like "/Images/main_333.jpg"
   // the idea is to grab the alt tab number and then add it to the href string to get the correct image
  }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you change `href` attribute? You can use `data-src` attribute, too.

Comment: @Janis I tried, but I'm assuming you have to use beforeLoad to load the href you want and I can't seem to push it to the right attribute to change it

Comment: No, I was wondering why you want to change it inside fancybox, why don't you just update on the page itself.

Comment: Basically how it works is you hover over the thumbnail, but that actual image I want to display is something else.

Comment: Sorry, I just do not get it - what stops you from setting final value for `href` and/or `data-src` attribute on the element directly (btw, you can use both attributes, if needed).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to change URL:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  beforeLoad : function(instance, current) {
    current.src = 'https://loremly.com/640x480/';
  }
});
```

Comment: So when I run this, instance and current are undefined ( mainly because I think they aren't loaded yet ) so maybe beforeLoad isn't the way to go. When the user clicks on an area tag, it will load the thumbnail image in the fancybox. I need it to load another image instead of that thumbnail. If I use the instance, current, it will have to load the thumbnail image first

Comment: OK, I got lazy just once and did not create a demo, and, of course, you do not believe me. So, here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/rkcLd7so/ - it just works. Perfectly.

Comment: lol, I am not saying I don't believe you, and yes it does work in your case. I am thinking maybe since it is not an image tag it doesn't read it right away. Currently, I am getting undefined but let me work at it since if I can figure out what the issue is

Comment: But you did not create a full demo where your issue could be inspected, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I figured it out, I just changed the width, height and href on afterLoad, it seems to work. Thanks for your help